# Trying to add circles onto image from Photo Library iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building part of my app where you can:

1. upload photos
2. subsequently add circles onto these photos
3. save these photos with the circles on them

I'm able to do step 1, but need help for step 2 and 3.

Here is the code I have so far. Please let me know what's wrong.

```
@IBAction func openPhotoLibraryButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    imagePicked.image = image
    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
```

This is the part where I have trouble adding the circles into the image picked:

```
func DrawOnImage(imagePicked: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imagePicked.size)

    imagePicked.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
    context.setAlpha(1.0)
    context.setLineWidth(10.0)
    context.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    context.drawPath(using: .stroke)

    let myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return myImage!
}
```

The trouble I face is that the circles appear all over the screen and is not bounded onto the image. I want to export the image with the marked circles.

Comment: These 3 points are completely independent and if anything each of them deserves a separate question. Anyhow, the first seems to work for you. The second you claim it does not work but I copied your code in my project and used it and seem to work, I believe you will need to explain what is your desired result and what is your current result. The last point is missing a description on what exactly you want and where you have issues with it next to what you have tried.

Comment: Hey @MaticOblak, the last point refers to exporting the image with the added circles. When I export it now, it only exports the original image, without the circles. Could it be a view problem?

Comment: Just a little note: it is common to have function & variable names' first character be lowercase. –> `DrawOnImage(imagePicked:)` should be `drawOnImage(imagePicked:)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your first part is working. The second part I have tested and is working properly and for the third part I am not sure what you have even tried and am not sure what exactly do you mean by "Saving those photos". "Saving them where?" would be the most troublesome.

Anyway to complete the second and third part I have created a new application and ported your code into it then added the code to draw a few circles and save the image into temporary directory as PNG file. I have modernized your code a bit but I assure you yours works exactly as good.

To reproduce what I have done you need to create a new iOS single view application and change "ViewController.swift" file to contain the following:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        testDrawingToImage()
    }

    private func drawCircle(circle: (center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat), withColor color: UIColor, lineWidth: CGFloat, onImage image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        // Create canvas
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)

        // Draw fullsize image
        image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)

        // Draw circle
        color.setStroke()
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: circle.center.x-circle.radius, y: circle.center.y-circle.radius, width: circle.radius*2.0, height: circle.radius*2.0))
        path.lineWidth = lineWidth
        path.stroke()

        // Extract image
        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        // End current context
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return outputImage
    }


    private func testDrawingToImage() {

        // Get image from assets
        let image = UIImage(named: "test")

        // Have some var image on which we will keep drawing
        var newImage: UIImage? = image

        // Draw a few circles on it
        if let image = newImage {
            newImage = drawCircle(circle: (center: CGPoint(x: 200.0, y: 200.0), radius: 60.0), withColor: UIColor.green, lineWidth: 5.0, onImage: image)
        }
        if let image = newImage {
            newImage = drawCircle(circle: (center: CGPoint(x: 200.0, y: 200.0), radius: 80.0), withColor: UIColor.blue, lineWidth: 12.0, onImage: image)
        }
        if let image = newImage {
            newImage = drawCircle(circle: (center: CGPoint(x: 200.0, y: 200.0), radius: 140.0), withColor: UIColor.black, lineWidth: 6.0, onImage: image)
        }
        if let image = newImage {
            newImage = drawCircle(circle: (center: CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 100.0), radius: 40.0), withColor: UIColor.red, lineWidth: 30.0, onImage: image)
        }

        // Now save it to temporary directory
        if let image = newImage {
            let pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
            try? pngData?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "/outputImage.png"))
            print("All done!")
        }

    }

}
```

The code is commented and should speak by itself. It does expect you to also include an image in your asset catalog named "test" or nothing will happen since all the if statements will fail.

This was my result (original image on the left and resulting image on the right):

[image]

You can clearly see 4 circles drawn to image correctly. In my case the original image resolution was 1440 × 1080 which is important when defining circle coordinates; if your image will be very small then you will not see the circles as they will be drawn "off the screen".